# SQL: Earliest and latest record per ID, also relational to other IDs

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem Summary**

I have two tables, *signups* and *notifications*, which contains signups and notifications, where each notification can be seen as unique and have an ID.

A signup can be attributed to notification with ID X if it has happened before X and after notification X-1.

The data I have is given as:

*Signups*

| Signup Timestamp |
| --- |
| 2022-09-01 |
| 2022-09-05 |
| 2022-09-15 |
| 2022-09-24 |
| 2022-09-25 |
| 2022-09-29 |

*Notifications*

| ID | Notification Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-10 |
| 2 | 2022-09-20 |
| 3 | 2022-09-30 |

My goal is to create a table which looks like:

| ID | Notification Timestamp | Earliest Signup Timestamp | Latest Signup Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-10 | 2022-09-01 | 2022-09-09 |
| 2 | 2022-09-20 | 2022-09-15 | 2022-09-15 |
| 3 | 2022-09-30 | 2022-09-24 | 2022-09-29 |

But I can't get my head around creating a SQL query which achieves this?

Help much appreciated!

Comment: How are Notifications and Signups related?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Just that a signup can be attributed to notification with ID X if it has happened before X and after notification X-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right you want max and min from Signups which are between current notification and its predessor

```
select n.ID, n.NotificationTimestamp, min(s.SignupTimestamp) EarliestSignupTimestamp, max (s.SignupTimestamp) LatestSignupTimestamp
from Signup s
join (
   select ID, NotificationTimestamp, lag(NotificationTimestamp) over(order by ID) prevNT
   from Notifications
   ) n
   on (s.SignupTimestamp > n.prevNT or n.prevNT is null) and s.SignupTimestamp < n.NotificationTimestamp
group by n.ID, n.NotificationTimestamp
```

Comment: The table Notifications does not have SignupTimestamp. Please see data definition for the available columns.